# Can't get value from textarea in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, html-parsing

I'm having issues getting the value of text area in PHP (getting undefined).

My code is pretty simple. 
My HTML is:

```
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="submit_form.php">    
<input type="text" class="formInput" placeholder="Your Name" id="first_name" maxlength="50" size="20" />
<input type="text" class="formInput" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" maxlength="80" size="20" /> 
<textarea class="formInput" placeholder="Your Message" name="comments" id="comments" maxlength="1400" cols="20" rows="6"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="SubmitContactForm" class="myButton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My PHP:

```
echo $_POST['comments'];
```

This results in `undefined`, no matter what I write inside the textarea. I searched here for some solutions and found some stuff, like adding "name" and "id" and making them both different, adding `htmlspecialchars($_POST['comments'])` and so on, all of these solutions don't work. I will make a note and say that I can get the other fields values without any problems, just this textarea.

Any ideas what can be the problem?

Comment: are you sure the textarea element is inside the form in your html?

Comment: Try using Firebug / your browsers developer tools, and inspect the HTTP request. See if the value is being sent.

Comment: Your HTML does not include a Name attribute on the Textarea tag.

Comment: btw use name="comments", name is connected to POST variable

Comment: - The textarea is inside the <form></form>.
- I tried using the name attribute, still doesn't work :-/

Comment: @Shai: Without the name attribute it definitely can't work! So please provided some corrected code that still isn't working and add your form where your textarea is placed in!

Comment: @oktopus : I tried all the codes that were suggested so far, all of them result with undefined

Comment: @Shai Do you have any JavaScript on your page that does something with that textarea?

Comment: Yes, but I canceled it during all of these checks.

Comment: @Shai Are you sure? Can you narrow your problem down to only the `form`-tag, your textarea and a submit-button and still have that problem? I can't believe that. So some other parts of your page must influence it. So without knowing your other parts - how can we help you??
But still: Without a name-attribute it never can work.
Maybe you have another input-field with the same name somewhere in your form?

Comment: Is `$_POST['comments']` the string `"undefined"`? Or the PHP value `NULL`? PHP does not have a value called undefined. If it's the string, it sounds like some javascript in your page is setting the value.

Comment: So, it seems to (finally) work now. I restarted the web server and included the name attribute. Thank you all for your answers and guidelines, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the name-attribute for your textarea.
Add: `name="comments"` to it:

```
<textarea class="formInput" name="comments" placeholder="Your Message" id="comments" maxlength="1400" cols="20" rows="6"></textarea>
```

If it still doesn't show up, make sure that you send your form using `method="post"`

Answer (score 1):

You need a name attribute in your textarea
name="comments"

```
<textarea class="formInput" placeholder="Your Message" id="comments" name="comments" maxlength="1400" cols="20" rows="6"></textarea>
```

Comment: @Shai it must work with the name attribute else something other with your code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the name attribute. Your html should look like this

```
<textarea name="comments" class="formInput" placeholder="Your Message" id="comments" maxlength="1400" cols="20" rows="6"></textarea>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, not with the id or name attributes, even if both equal or different

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea class="formInput" placeholder="Your Message" id="comments" maxlength="1400" cols="20" rows="6" name="yourtextarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, not with the id or name attributes, even if both equal or different

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the script that *receives* the form post:

```
print "POST: " . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n"
   . "GET: " . print_r($_GET, true) . "\n";
```

If "comments" show up under "GET" then you haven't set the form's method=post

Comment: "undefined" usually pops up from JavaScript.  Do you have any client side scripts running against this?  Using jquery or another library?

Answer (score 0):

First define it like `$comment=$_POST['comments'];` after that you can do what you want,
**Note:** Don't use it directly like `$_POST['comments'];` because in some cases it will thrown some error's/notices etc..

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the form attribute of textarea. In this you set the id of your form. Added advantage is that this allows you to place your textarea outside the form as well.
Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score -1):

Remove some of your `textarea` class like

```
<textarea name="Address" rows="3" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="Your Address" ></textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea name="Address" rows="3" class="full-width" placeholder="Your Address" ></textarea>
```

It depends on your template (Purchased Template).
Develop including some of JavaScript to get value from correct object on UI
but for elements like `input-text` just find `$('input[type=text]')`.